# Some 404 not founds after use Assetics

Tags: javascript, php, css, symfony

i try to work with assetics on Symfony2.

```
        {% stylesheets 'bundles/gestutilisateurs/css/*' filter="cssrewrite" output='css/compiled/main.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
        {% endstylesheets %}

        {% javascripts '@GestUtilisateursBundle/Resources/public/js/plugins/*' 
       '@GestUtilisateursBundle/Resources/public/js/*' 
       output='js/compiled/main.js' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
```

Symfony generate my JS, and my css without problems
But now on chrome i have somes issues :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
main_part_1_npm_3.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
main_part_1_ripples.min.js_5.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
main_part_2_material.min.js_4.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
jquery.min.map:1 GET http://localhost/Symfony/web/js/compiled/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)
```

(Same for 5 files (i can only put 1 link x) )

He searchs always  file with .map extension but i don't have this on my folder
So how i can repair that ?

I change in my config use_controller to false, clear cache, dump assetics, but nothing
I have already read the cookbook, so i hope someone can explain me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to fix the 404 error for the jquery map. Google and find a download. Then you need to fix your javascript error in this file: main_part_1_npm_3.js

Comment: Ok now i have the map of jquery, but other error from js, i think it's symfony. Because i have one issue in jquery, one in bootstrap material design, i didn't touch anything

Comment: Is symphony up to date?